# Surefire doesn't run PowerMock test

Tags: maven, junit, powermock, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to use inheritance with a PowerMock-enhanced JUnit test. But Maven surefire doesn't seem to recognize it as a test.

AbstractTest.java:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class AbstractTest {
}
```

ConcreteTest.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({}) // <-- this line causes the test not to be found by Surefire
public class ConcreteTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

Try to run the test:

> mvn -Dtest=ConcreteTest.java test

With the @PrepareForTest annotation, I get the surefire error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test
>   (default-test) on project com.ciphercloud.plugin.crypto: No tests were
>   executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help
>   1]

If I comment it out, it works as expected:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Am I doing something wrong? How do I get it to work?

Comment: Facing same issue did you find any solution?

Comment: @Gajukorse I don't recall if I found a solution, sorry. But try upgrading Maven.